# I would like to set up a goal so that the funnel displays total users too

Tags: google-analytics

The structure of the web site is as follows:

- a number of pages with the call to action, clicking on it it takes to /CTA
- /CTA is the first step of the funnel and contains the link to step2 /CTA2
- /CTA2 is the second step that takes to the destination /CTA3

I'm setting up a goal with destination /CTA3 and two steps: /CTA and /CTA2. 
So far all good, when I inspect the funnel visualization I can see how many has started the funnel, from where, drop rate to other steps etc.

I'd love to insert an additional step, before the first: this new step should indicate all the visitors who has seen at least one page (as said many pages has the call to action).
Basically to know what % of visitors clicked on the CTA.

Is it possible to have a goal with /CTA3 as destination and

- [any page] as first step
- /CTA as second step
- /CTA2 as third step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use regular expression:
`.*` - any page.

Notice that matching type sets for final step and is the same for all steps.

Comment: Didn't know that matching type set for the final step is also used for all steps, great! Thanks